# Populate rows of one workbook with calculation results from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have one workbook (calculation workbook) that does a huge number of calculations based on a small number of inputs, say X, Y, and Z, and spits out the results A and B.

I have another workbook (data workbook) full of millions of rows of data. I want to take X, Y, and Z from each row in this workbook, plug them into the calculation workbook so that it calculates A and B, and then automatically pull A and B from the calculation workbook back into the data workbook.

I realize this operation will probably take a long time but it's still easy than doing it manually and I can always refine it to fewer rows later.

Is there a simple way to this via VBA?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please note the comment above - you've been here long enough to know you're expected to put in some work before posting...

That said, this should get you started.

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsCalcs As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Range
    
    Set wsData = Workbooks("Data.xlsx").Worksheets("Data")
    Set wsCalcs = Workbooks("Calcs.xlsx").Worksheets("Model")
    
    'adjust ranges and addresses to suit...
    For Each rw In wsData.Range("A1:E1000").Rows
        'populate inputs
        wsCalcs.Range("D1").Value = rw.Cells(1).Value
        wsCalcs.Range("D2").Value = rw.Cells(2).Value
        wsCalcs.Range("D3").Value = rw.Cells(3).Value
        wsCalcs.Calculate
        DoEvents
        'record outputs
        rw.Cells(4).Value = wsCalcs.Range("E1").Value
        rw.Cells(5).Value = wsCalcs.Range("E2").Value
    Next rw
End Sub
```